# how to save integer valuses to the text file

Tags: python, loops, file, detection

I am trying to detect persons on  image and  the aim is saving the information of bounding boxes and confidence value as values with corresponding confidence and bounding box to the  text file . But i got errors  `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` or  `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray`

```
 for i in np.arange(0, person_detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = person_detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence > 0.5:
            idx = int(person_detections[0, 0, i, 1])

            if CLASSES[idx] != "person":
                continue

            person_box = person_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = person_box.astype("int")
                        
            preds = np.append(person_box, confidence) # Add confidence to array
            preds_string = preds.tostring() # Convert array to string

            # To convert back to numpy array
            bbox = np.fromstring(preds_string, dtype=int) 
            
            info = open("output.txt","w")
            info.write(bbox)
            info.close
```

I can't get it to save and write the them to a text file, this is my code above, I would appreciate any help if possible, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you cannot pass an object of type `numpy.ndarray` to `write` (that is, you cannot write your array to a text file the way you are trying to do it). `numpy` has functions for that (see [`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)).

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> preds_string = '1 2'
>>> bbox = np.fromstring(preds_string, dtype=int, sep=' ')
>>>
>>> with open("output.txt","w") as info:
...     np.savetxt(info, bbox, fmt='%d')
...
```

```
$ cat output.txt      
1
2
```

Comment: also we can do this

`var3 = " ".join([str(person_box), str(confidence)])  myText = open(r'output.txt','w') myText.write(var3) myText.close()
`